# how do i join 7 tables where a column (which exists in all tables) equals the same content in all tables?

Tags: php, mysql

i have seen how to inner join 2 tables where a column is equal to the content in another column. but how do i do this with 7 tables?'

thanks everyone,
I figured it out lol after a long time. this seems to work

```
SELECT *
FROM
  tbl_school
  INNER JOIN tbl_apprequirments ON (tbl_school.schoolname = tbl_apprequirments.schoolname)
  INNER JOIN tbl_citygallery ON (tbl_apprequirments.schoolname = tbl_citygallery.schoolname)
  INNER JOIN tbl_schoolgallery ON (tbl_citygallery.schoolname = tbl_schoolgallery.schoolname)
  INNER JOIN tbl_livingexp ON (tbl_schoolgallery.schoolname = tbl_livingexp.schoolname)
  INNER JOIN tbl_tuition ON (tbl_livingexp.schoolname = tbl_tuition.schoolname)

  where tbl_school.schoolname = 'glendale community college';
```

Comment: I think it would help if you were more specific and included an example of your tables

Comment: if you look at this image http://navidoor.com/img.jpg you'll notice all the tables have a column named schoolname. what i basically need to do is run a join query with all the tables where the schoolname = "something"

Comment: If you need to join 7 tables make sure all the join columns are indexed (in all tables).

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 JOIN t3 JOIN t4 JOIN t5
  ON (t2.c=t1.c AND t3.c=t1.c AND t4.c=t1.c AND t5.c=t1.c)
```

MySQL provides a shorthand for this:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN (t2, t3, t4, t5)
  ON (t2.c=t1.c AND t3.c=t1.c AND t4.c=t1.c AND t5.c=t1.c)
```

This example is for 5 tables. You can repeat as necessary.

See MySQL's [join syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Edit: after seeing the clarification from sarmenhb, I think this query also works:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN (t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7)
  USING (schoolname)
  WHERE t1.schoolname = 'name'
```

Comment: @Stephan202, I'm sure the OP will get the idea. :)

Comment: select * from tbl_school JOIN (tbl_tuition,tbl_livingexp,tbl_schoolgallery,tbl_apprequirments,tbl_citygallery)
USING (schoolname)
where tbl_school.`schoolname` = 'glendale community college';

Comment: got an error doing that, error is Invalid Token 'where' at position 1 of line 3

Comment: @sarmenhb - It works for me. Are you using MySQL or something else? Could you please also try the syntax in the first query?

Answer (score 1):

After joining 2 of them, join the thrid to the first two, then the 4th to the first 3, etc,

```
  Select *
   From T1 Join T2 On  <criteria>
           Join T3, on <criteria>
           Join T4 On <Criteria>
            etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
Select data
from table as tbl1
join as tbl2 on tbl2.data = tbl1.data
join as tbl3 on tbl3.data = tbl1.data
```

is this what you are looking for?